# How to know that the navigate function didnt work [VBA]

Tags: forms, vba, internet-explorer

How do I prove that navigate function worked? I have this code:

```
 Dim oBrowser As InternetExplorer
 Set oBrowser = New InternetExplorer
 oBrowser.Visible = True 'oBrowser.Silent = True
 oBrowser.navigate "www.google.com"
```

I tried looking [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752093(v=vs.85).aspx) but I don't get it: the return value is a long type? I tried:

```
 Dim test as long
 test = oBrowser.navigate "www.google.com"
 msgbox test
 'to see the value of the return
```

But it wont work

Comment: @Awesome33 I accidentally down-voted you, so I had to edit your question a little and I've changed it to the up-vote now. Apologies for any confusion, it's a dreary, rain filled morning in Dublin and my brain isn't in gear!

Comment: NP thanks to you it works just fine now

Comment: And if there no internet access ? is there a way to send an Error msg if there is no internet acecss?

Comment: Hey, yeah you could try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/551613/check-for-active-internet-connection  or http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-excel/check-internet-availability-using-vba/627e3bc4-2168-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5 as a jumping off point

Comment: Woah that's it I love you!

Comment: I.. don't know how to reply to that! :) glad to have helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to the other answer: You could just use the below code, and not worry at all about the return of navigate. You could use MsgBox (as I have below to match your question), you could use a Boolean Success = True / False where relative, or just an old Debug.Print("Success/Error") where needed.

Then add the error handling into that.

```
Sub ie_open()
    On Error Goto MyErrorCode

    Dim ie As Object
    Set ie = CreateObject("INTERNETEXPLORER.APPLICATION")
    ie.NAVIGATE "http://www.google.com"
    ie.Visible = True

    MsgBox "Hurray this worked!"

    MyErrorCode:
        MsgBox "An error Occured!" & Err

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you properly you want to know whether the code snippet works or not? Right? If that's the case you simply do some error handling and if there's an error then you will know that there's some error. An example is below

```
   If IsError(write statement you want to test) Then
        goto errorMessage
     Else
   'do something if there is a match
      End If
    errorMessage:
  'The handling of the error
```

Comment: Thta's the probleme i can't get the return value from the oBrowser.navigate