# Check if it is connected to the Internet

Tags: vba, office365, powerpoint, internet-connection

I am creating an operating system and there will be updates. I want VBA to check if there is an active Internet connection through WiFi or Ethernet. If the check is successful, then it sends you to a certain slide, but if it failed, then it sends you to another slide

This is the code I tried and it's not working:

```
Private Function IsInternetConnected(Optional SupressMessage As Boolean) As Boolean

Dim objHTTP As Object

'Test for Internet Connection
  If IsInternetConnected = True Then
  ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.GotoSlide 3
End

'Report to User if Internet Connection not detected
  If IsInternetConnected = False And SupressMessage = False Then
    ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.GotoSlide 2
  End If

End Function
```

Comment: Have you any error message to share so the community can help in a better way ?

Comment: Unfortunately, not. It doesn't send me anywhere and I don't get a single error code

Comment: Hello everyone, finally, after a year, I managed to make the code work. The only thing I had to do, not specified anywhere, was to add a shape to which I assigned the action that would start the macro.

Comment: Gret to hear ! May you write an answer to mark your question as resolved ? (You'll have to accept your own answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to make the code work. The only thing I had to do, not specified anywhere, was to add a shape to which I assigned the action that would start the macro. Here is the code:

```
Sub InternetCheck()

    Dim objSlide As Slide
    Dim objShape As Shape
    Dim strURL As String
    Dim blnConnected As Boolean

    strURL = "http://www.bing.com"

    On Error Resume Next
    Set objXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    objXMLHTTP.Open "GET", strURL, False
    objXMLHTTP.Send
    If objXMLHTTP.Status = 200 Then
        blnConnected = True
    Else
        blnConnected = False
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    If blnConnected Then
        ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.GotoSlide (3)
    Else
        ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.GotoSlide (2)
    End If

End Sub
```

To start the code, it must be automated with a module that calls the macro.

Comment: Good answer, what references need to be enabled? bing.com would not be my choice of URL as it tends to be cluttered with news feeds. Other search engines are available.

Comment: http://example.com/ is also a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

You might do this, using Windows API:

```
#If Win64 Then
  Private Declare PtrSafe Function InternetGetConnectedState _
    Lib "wininet.dll" (lpdwFlags As LongPtr, _
      ByVal dwReserved As Long) As Boolean
#Else
  Private Declare Function InternetGetConnectedState _
    Lib "wininet.dll" (lpdwFlags As Long, _
      ByVal dwReserved As Long) As Boolean
#End If

Private Function IsInternetConnected(Optional SupressMessage As Boolean) As Boolean

    Dim bConnected As Boolean

    bConnected = InternetGetConnectedState(0&, 0&)
    'Test for Internet Connection
    If bConnected Then
        ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.GotoSlide 3
    End If

    'Report to User if Internet Connection not detected
    If Not bConnected And Not SupressMessage Then
        ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.GotoSlide 2
    End If

    IsInternetConnected = bConnected
End Function
```

Ref.

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wininet/nf-wininet-internetgetconnectedstate
2. [Check for active internet connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/551613/check-for-active-internet-connection)

[image]
After testing

- with Ethernet cable disconnected, InternetGetConnectedState(0&, 0&)
  returns false,
- on the other hand, with Ethernet cable connected again
  to my PC, InternetGetConnectedState(0&, 0&) returns true.

This Windows DLL function works fine.

Comment: Hi. I put the code in Vba and it doesn't work. It doesn't send me to the right slide if I'm connected to the internet or not. By the way, where do I put the API?

Comment: Just put this code before Private Function IsInternetConnected.

Comment: Here's what happening:  [photo](https://ibb.co/q5Snrq8)

Comment: Please comment BOOL  InternetGetConnectedState (...); this is not Visual Basic.

Comment: I think writing slide numbers is not working because it doesn't send me to any slides. Do you want me to send you the file?

Comment: Sorry I've only an empty .ppt doc for testing, there is only VBA code in it. This void presentation will not help you, but enables debuggering if InternetGetConnectedState() function works.

Comment: Do you have discord or something so I can send it to you?

Comment: I'm very sorry, this will be out of the scope of the forum.

Comment: So, the first 3 slides need to do the following:
Slide 1: Internet check via VBA
Slide 2: Internet verification failed
Slide 3: Internet verification was successful

VBA: Checks if there is an active connection and sends you to slide 3, but if you don't have an active connection, it sends you to slide 2

Comment: Sorry there is an error at the line Not bConnected , please correct this. Code updated/

Comment: I found the problem! It is not sending me to the slide written in code when i am on slide show

Comment: So, you're not going to help me??

Comment: How can I help you?

Comment: So please make a presentation like in this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75503509/check-if-it-is-connected-to-the-internet/75503861?noredirect=1#comment133229056_75503861)